# Getting genymotion to run on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I want to run genymotion on my Ubuntu OS. i have downloaded and installed the bin file. Virtual box is also present and has been detected by the installation. The installed folder is owned by my current username with all access.

When i double click on genymotion application, nothing happens. Am i missing something that needs to be done? any ideas.

Comment: run it like this: ´cd path/to/genymotion´ and then ´./genymotion´ and please tell me what happens (if you see a error log post it here)

Comment: it is installed in the downloads folder. when i go to the terminal and type in './genymotion', it says 

./genymotion: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /home/maxes/Downloads/genymotion/libQtGui.so.4)
./genymotion: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /home/maxes/Downloads/genymotion/libQtNetwork.so.4)
./genymotion: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /home/maxes/Downloads/genymotion/libQtCore.so.4)

Comment: check this link http://scriptogr.am/dzinek/post/genymotion-qt-gentoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install virtualbox so that the genymotion application will work.

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/softwares$ sudo chmod +x genymotion-2.1.0_x64.bin
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/softwares$ sudo ./genymotion-2.1.0_x64.bin
Installing to folder [/home/avinash/softwares/genymotion]. Are you sure [y/n] ? y


- Trying to find VirtualBox toolset .................... OK (Valid version of VirtualBox found: 4.3.6r91406)
- Extracting files ..................................... OK (Extract into: [/home/avinash/softwares/genymotion])

Installation done successfully.

You can now use these tools from [/home/avinash/softwares/genymotion]:
 - genymotion
 - genymotion-shell

avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/softwares$
```

[image]

After the genymotion.bin file was installed, a genymotion directory was created.Go inside that folder and double click on genymotion application to work.

Comment: i have virtualbox installed. it did say valid version of virtualbox found

Comment: Does it says "Installation done successfully"?

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l ~/Downloads/genymotion/genymotion`

Comment: this is the output ` -rwxr-xr-x 1 maxes 1004 1483055 2014-02-04 13:24 /home/maxes/Downloads/genymotion/genymotion`

Comment: Try these commands, `cd ~/Downloads/genymotion` and `sudo ./genymotion`

Comment: The above commands try to run the genymotion file from terminal.It creates a log file(whether the commands executes successfully or not) through that we can know what the problem is.

Comment: i solved the issue by upgrading my linux from 11.10 to 12.04. the problem was that the libc6 library isnt upto the version required by genymotion in 11.10.